# Improving Performance of large DataContext

Tags: performance, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I am working with a DataContext that has 145 tables with many references. I have read a few articles and posts about wether it is better to split up DataContexts in such cases and the best practice seems to be to work with one large DataContext. Performance should not be greatly influenced because the DataContext is loaded into memory.

Nevertheless my tests have shown that just instantiating my DataContext takes about 90ms every time, after I reduced the number of tables it was instant.

For example, this code takes almost 10 seconds:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 100
   Using db As New MyDataContext()
   End Using
Next
```

Is there a way to improve the performance of the DataContext with many tables or should i try to use multiple DataContexts?

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is wise or not to divide your DataContext into smaller separate collections of DbSets depends on whether your tables are related and on what type of database management system that you are using.

If you use a professional DBMS, like Microsoft DBMS, then for this DBMS 145 tables is not a lot to handle. There wouldn't be any problem if you keep all your tables in one database.

It might be that splitting up your tables into separate databases might lead to problems in the future if one of your tables becomes dependant of one of the tables in the other database.

On the other hand, for a simple DBMS like SQLight, a lot of tables, and a lot of simultaneous queries might be too much for it.

If your tables really have nothing to do with each other, consider splitting them into separate databases. For instance if you have a database with Customers, Products, Orders, Prices, Invoices, etc, and another database with Schools, Students, Courses, ClassRooms, Teachers, etc. It is very unlikely that any of the School tables will ever relate to the Orders tables.

Event if you decide later to add a table with Addresses, with primary key PostCode + HouseNumber. In your invoice database Customers have Addresses. On your School database Schools, Teachers, Students have Addresses.

If you had separate databases, you had to implement (and fill!) the addresses twice. If John Doe, who is a Customer as well as a Teacher in a School moves to a different city, you'll have to change the Address twice.

On the other hand, a separate database would give you the opportunity to first add the Addresses as a separate table in the invoice database, and later in the Schools database. You can even decide to let Invoices have a different address system than Schools. Or maybe you want you invoice system have a different Addresses table than your School system.

So whether or not you should split:

- Can your DBMS handle large amounts of data?
- Are you tables related? Do you expect relations in the future?
- If there are common tables: is it a problem to implement it twice?
- Will this lead to duplicate data, where you have to implement changes twice?
- Do you want the possibility to have a different table in the two databases?

The reason that the dbContext is in local memory doesn't qualify. The DbContext does not hold the data of the database, it only holds the potential to query data.

Some types of DbContext (entity framework for instance) however also remember data that has already been fetched. Usually people keep a dbContext only alive for a short time, to prevent that you miss changes made by others when querying data. So even in that case this does not effect your choice of having one or two databases.